# Gridview not displaying data

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

this is my gridview page.

```
    style="top: 315px; left: 47px; position: absolute; height: 121px; width: 979px" 
    AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderWidth="1px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartureTime" HeaderText="DepartureTime" 
            SortExpression="DepartureTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" 
            SortExpression="Comments" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" 
            SortExpression="Time" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Data" HeaderText="Data" 
            SortExpression="Data" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Locations" HeaderText="Location" 
            SortExpression="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Destination" HeaderText="Destination" 
            SortExpression="Destination" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TrackingID" HeaderText="TrackingID" 
            SortExpression="TrackingID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Shipper" HeaderText="Shipper" 
            SortExpression="Shipper" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
            SortExpression="Address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Receiver" HeaderText="Receiver" SortExpression="Receiver" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Origin" HeaderText="Origin" 
            SortExpression="Origin" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReceiverAddres" HeaderText="ReceiverAddres" 
            SortExpression="ReceiverAddres" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sqlConStr %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [trackingInfo] WHERE ([TrackingID] = @TrackingID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="trackingnumber" Name="TrackingID" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is my form page.

this work well when i created is using visual studio and sql management studio
but when i hosted it to my windows web hosting and use the database in my control panel which webadmin is admin software there. this gridview stops working and its showing this error message "Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.

Web Server at mydomin.org.uk "
i have checked my connectionstring at the web.config file that is good there is no problem there. 
please help me for i have put in all ideal to this but is not working.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

kindly manage your connection string in web.config file......

```
<ConnectionStrings>
<!--Live--><add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="server=64.5.122.60;user id=user123;password=password;database=databaseName;port=9293" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>

    <!--Local--><add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=databaseName;port=3306" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</ConnectionStrings>
```

Hope it helpss

Comment: thanks Muhammad but how do i know the port number and also am using MSSQL

Comment: The SQL query SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname' will show you the hostname of the MySQL server which you can easily resolve to its IP address.

SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port' Will give you the port number.

You can find details about this in MySQL's manual: 12.4.5.41. SHOW VARIABLES Syntax and 5.1.4. Server System Variables

Comment: i have change my connectionstring in web.config file into this        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=108.163.224.235;Database=databsename; User ID=databaseuser;password=mypassword;"
      providerName="MSSQL.Data.MSSqlClient" />
   
    
   <add name="sqlConStr" connectionString="Data Source=108.163.224.235; Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=databaseuser;Password=mypassword;" providerName="MSSQL.Data.MSSqlClient"></add>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Thanks so Much Muhammad i have change to MySQL and use the codes you gave me and it work for me i can now access my database. the login page is working fine now. but the gridview has not started working pls look into my codes again and know if there is something am missing. thanks so much.

Comment: kindly check your Grid Data source or check the connection string defined in your SqlDataSource...  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sqlConStr %>"    when you configure the connection string name defined in web.config is the same then it will works fine for you.... thanks.

Comment: ConnectionString define in my web.config is same with the connectionString in my SqlDataSource but is still showing error 404 Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.

Comment: Try to re-define the SqlDataSource and debug on local server if works then deploy to server.

Comment: I have re-define the sqlDataSource and debug it on local server it works well then i upload it the webform to site it starts to show 404 again

Comment: I don't know why this is happening now If would at your place will bind the gird manual to avoid this problem. so my advice is bind the grid manully .... thanks

Comment: pls give me the procedure to bind the grid manully. thanks so much for your concern and assistance.

Comment: thanks so much for your help so far i am thinking that this might be the cause should i change this. to look ----- <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=108.163.224.235;Integrated Security=SSPI; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> like ----<add name="sqlConStr" connectionString="server=Local MySQL server;user id=swift_mydy;password=A#!~GOD;database=swiftdata;port=3306" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: don't change local ConnectionString  <add name="sqlConStr" ....>  to <add name="ApplicationServices" ....> because in your application GridView data source or you can say SqlDataSource ConnectionString refers the name sqlConStr ... so don't change the name on live server keep it same as it is, but do others settings in web.config ConnectionString tag like server,port,user id, password... etc. thanks

Comment: this is the error am having after adding the codes u gave to me http://mydomain.org.uk/mycustompage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/results.aspx Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.

Web Server at mydomain.org.uk pls i still need some help i know i have stressed u but still help me pls

Comment: Dear I tried my best to solve your problem.... and code that I gave you did work on local or not...?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BindGrid();
}
private void BindGrid()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConStr"].ConnectionString); 
    string sql = "Select * from tableName;";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql,connection);                                                                        
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(datatable);
    GridView1.DataSource=datatable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

This will bind your grid manuly... hope this will help you again... thanks